# Syncing data from flutter app to server in background

Tags: android, flutter

I'm developing a timer app with flutter which should sync it's time to my server on a fixed repeating intervals. So, when user starts a timer - application should send something like confirmation 'Timer is running' to my server each 5 minutes even if phone is locked.
I tried implement it with [android alarm manager plugin](https://pub.dev/packages/android_alarm_manager) using following method:

```
await AndroidAlarmManager.oneShot(Duration(minutes: 5), MY_ID, syncFn, exact: true, allowWhileIdle: true);
```

the syncFn sends a request to my server and then re-schedules the same alarm, so it looks like this:

```
static void syncFn() async {
    try{
      // send confirmation that app is running to my server
      await BackgrdoundService().sync();
    } catch (err) {
      print(err);
    } finally {
      await AndroidAlarmManager.oneShot(Duration(minutes: 5), MY_ID, syncFn, exact: true, allowWhileIdle: true);
    }
  }
```

when I start my timer - syncFn executes without issues first time even if phone is locked but when this method is executed while phone is locked - it is not firing next time after 5 minutes anymore. Also, it is not firing even after 15 minutes, it will fire only when the phone screen is unlocked or phone charger connected.

I understand, that this is caused by OS battery usage optimizations, but I don't understand how to avoid it.

I'm new to mobile app development, and if such approach of sending data from mobile app to server is wrong, please let me know about it. I've read about FCM but as I can see it's for downstream messaging and cannot be used in my case.
Also, I tried to use other android alarm manager methods, like periodic (issue with this method is that it's not exact periodic) and play with arguments, but didn't notice improvements

Thank you for reading and help!

Answer (score 1):

First you need to check where your background service is not running, or alarm manager is not triggering. Add a log before

```
await BackgrdoundService().sync();
```

Because might be Android is limiting background services. Check this link for more info
https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background

Secondly, it's better to use WorkManager instead of AlarmManager because it's deprecated in android.

If the problem is background service limit, then instead of running service, put your logic here in function.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, WorkManager has minimal period of 15 minutes which is too big for me. I think start implementing Foreground Service